# a bout cohomology module

Tags: commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $(R,m,k)$ be a local Cohen-Macaulay ring with dim $R=d\geq 2$ and $\mu(m)=n$. let
$$0\to L\to R^n \to R\to R/m \to 0$$
denoted the intial part of a minimal free resolution of $R/m$ and let $\{e_i\}$ be the standard basis of $R^n$. if $m=<x_1,...,x_n>$ we denote $f_{ij}=x_ie_j-x_je_i$ and $K=<f_{ij}>$. let

$N:=mL+K$ and $M=R^n/N$.

How to show that dim$M=d$ and
$H^0_m(M)=L/N$ and $H^1_m(M)=R/m$ and for $2\leq i \leq d-1$, $H^i_m(M)=0$

thanks for hellp

Comment: Not sure how much it helps, but by the “ext definition” of depth (Stacks, Lemma 10.72.5), the local cohomology of $R$ is $0$ up to degree $d-1$ (included). You also have an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow L/N \rightarrow M \rightarrow m \rightarrow 0$, with $L/N$ being a $R/m$-vector space, which should help you with the first cohomology groups.

Comment: $H^0_m(M)$ can be computed by $m$-torsion functor. For $i>0$, notice in this case $H^i_m(M)\cong H^i_m(m)$ and the short exact sequence $0\longrightarrow m\longrightarrow R\longrightarrow R/m\longrightarrow 0$. Then you can use Grothendieck's vanishing theorem to the long exact sequence of local cohomology.